# Align environment creates extra vertical space

Tags: spacing, align

I'm typing a very large document (a thesis) and at some point align environment produces abnormally large vertical space before and after equation. I double-checked that it is neither in the beginning nor in the end of a paragraph. And the weird thing is that, when I copy the problematic piece of code and create a new document containing it alone, spacing is perfectly normal (hence, presenting it here is pointless). Also this abnormal spacing thing happens only once in the whole original document, although similar codes are used frequently.

My question is, what do you recommend me to check?

Comment: if you have flushbottom set  the space around the align may be the only space than can be stretched to bring the baseline of the last line on the page to the bottom of the page

Comment: By "beginning" and "end of a paragraph" you mean that you do not have empty lines around the `align` environment and the paragraph content?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for your comment, I didn't use flushbottom.

Comment: @Werner, yes I mean exactly that.

Comment: which document class are you using? (an MWE is always useful:-)

Comment: I'm using a custom document class prepared by my institute

Comment: given that you accepted barbaras answer I assume that it is using flushbottom (or the space wouldn't stetch in that case)

Comment: I'm sorry, that makes sense. I meant by I didn't use it, I didn't add that declaration myself, but apparently I was using it without knowing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is stretchable space inserted before and after any multi-line display structure
when `amsmath` is used.  (stretchable space is similarly inserted around single-line
displays, but they aren't as susceptible to the surrounding context.)

take a look at what appears on the following page.  if there is another large multi-line
display near the top (preceded by only one or two lines of text), it isn't by default
allowed to break the display if it doesn't fit on the previous page.  instead, the
stretchable gaps (around displays, before section headings, between paragraphs -- all
to a different degree) are stretched to produce a bottom-aligned page.

this isn't really what you usually want, as you have observed.

if you are willing to allow the long display on the second page to break, you can approach
this in the following ways:

- if you are willing to allow breaks in displays throughout the whole document, place
  the command `\allowdisplaybreaks` in the preamble;
- if you want to be selective about where a long display breaks, insert `\displaybreak`
  immediately before the `\\` in the display where it is to take effect.

additional possibilities are described in the `amsmath` documentation (`texdoc amsmath`).

another possibility is that a box of some sort (e.g. a minipage) or other large
unbreakable element appears near the top of the "second" page.  the tactics for
dealing with such a situation depend on what kind of element it is.

Comment: I think your answer addresses my problem. the next page begins with a section title, and if the space before/after align would be removed, that section title would sit on the bottom of the page, and would look much worse.

Comment: @Macond -- if you would rather see a short page, then `\clearpage` before the section title is your friend.  obviously, putting in such directives is best left until you're (nearly) done revising your text.