# Too much white space above and below equation in two column mode

Tags: two-column

I'm converting a paper to two column mode (using \documentclass[twocolumn]{article}) , and one of my equations now has too much white space above and below it.  See the attached image (equation (8)).  How can I fix this?

[image]

I don't know how to provide a minimal working example in this case, but here is a snippet of Latex code surrounding the equation:

```
\subsubsection{Moreau-Yosida regularization}
\label{mySection}
Convex analysis provides an elegant way of smoothing out nondifferentiable
convex functions.
Let $f: \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R \cup \{ \infty \}$ be closed and convex.
The Moreau-Yosida regularization of $f$ with parameter $t > 0$ is defined by
\begin{equation}
\label{myRegDef}
f^{(t)}(x) = \inf_{u \in \mathbb R^m} f(u) + \frac{1}{2t} \| u - x\|_2^2.
\end{equation}
It can be shown that $f^{(t)}:\mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R$ is a convex, \emph{differentiable}
approximation to $f$, and that the gradient of $f^{(t)}$ is given by the formula
\begin{equation}
\label{myGrad}
\nabla f^{(t)}(x) = \frac{1}{t} (x - \prox_{tf}(x)).
\end{equation}
The gradient of $f^{(t)}$ is Lipschitz continuous with Lipschitz
constant $L = 1/t$.
```

Comment: It's quite difficult to reproduce this (`\prox`???) because this depends somewhat on the content before the `\subsubsection`...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer That's true, but I also don't think I should post the entire paper (or first seven pages of it) as a minimal working example.  I wonder if this is a commonly encountered problem when converting to two column mode, and if there are standard tricks for dealing with it.

Comment: Try the directive `\raggedbottom` in your preamble.

Comment: Or try `\allowdisplaybreaks` in your preamble if you have multi-line displayed equations.

Comment: if what starts on page 8 is large and unbreakable, and you have only one math display on the second column of p.7, this is the result you will get.  look at [Align environment creates extra vertical space](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/202785/579); the same thing happens with *any* display material.